# What are the fuel requirements for Canadian flights?

Tags: flight-planning, fuel, transport-canada

I am aware of the "US Flag Jet", "Piston" and "Domestic" policies in the US, and the ICAO policies. Is there a specific requirement in Canada for domestic and also international flights? Does Transport Canada have their own regulations, or do they use the ICAO or US ones?

I'm asking this for use in simulation but I'd imagine this is also a valid question in the real world.

Comment: @mins yes, I mean minimums and reserves. And having trouble finding a link to these. I know they're options in PFPX, a popular flight planning and dispatch tool for FSX and P3D.

Comment: The applicable regulations are found in [this circular](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/standards/commerce-circulars-ac0234-1523.htm). See also CAR [705.25, Fuel Requirements, Operator Responsibility](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-96-433/page-145.html).